# collect all errors from a Flux<Void>

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have a `Flux<Message>`, and a `Mono<Void> process(Message m)` function. The `process` function can return an error or nothing. I want to call the `process` function in parallel, and collect all the messageId that has an process error into `List<String>`.

```
@Data
class Message {
    String messageId;
    String content;    
}

Flux.just(new Message("A", "1"), new Message("B", "2"))
    .flatMap(m -> 
        process(m).onErrorReturn(m.messageId)
    )
```

But the problem is I can't return a type other than `Void` in the `onErrorXXX` methods.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a wrapper that will contains messageId and the error message like this:

```java
@Value
private static class ProcessingError {
    private final String id;
    private final String message;
    private final boolean hasError;
}

Flux.just(new Message("A", "1"), new Message("B", "2"))
    .flatMap(m -> process(m).thenReturn(new ProcessingError(m.messageId, null, false))
                            .onErrorResume(th -> Mono.just(new ProcessingError(m.messageId, th.getMessage(), true))));
```

Now the flux after the `flatMap` is a `Flux<ProcessingError>` and you can filter only the one with `hasError = true` and then collect the way you want.